# how can i get order status label of a specific store using store id in magento 2.?

Tags: magento2, orders, order-status

In the below code i am getting order status label of a the default store.But i want the store specific label.please help me .

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orders = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId)->setOrder(
              'created_at',
              'desc'
          )
                      'created_at',
                      'desc'
                  );
```

Answer (score 3):

### EDIT

In such case, you have to use   `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\CollectionFactory` which will you give the list of the status label of that store. 
`sales_order_status` table is related to that collection.

### OLD

Please try with

```
getStatusLabel()
```

Also you should select the field **status**  `addFieldToFilter('status')` to collection

Comment: Actually i have 2 store view one is english and another is arabic, so currently i am getting the status of default store(english).But i am not getting the label in arabic. i have added arabic in backend but not getting it.

Comment: have u understand what i want to tell you? Is this store label is not  only comming for your code or whole website?

Comment: actually i need to get store specific status label using store id.